# Why can't I install nvidia driver on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: nvidia, software-installation

I did the following link to install Nvidia driver on Ubuntu 12.10

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=813931&highlight=nvidia#post_5086971

But I don't know why I get error "installation failed".

I have to notice that I didn't found xorg.conf in the 6th step

here is my installation log from nvidia-installer.log  file :

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Mon Jan 13 19:28:43 2014
installer version: 331.20

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> License accepted.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 331.20.
-> Running distribution scripts
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
-> done.
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Continue installation anyway? (Answer: Yes)
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="cc".
ERROR: Unable to find the kernel source tree for the currently running kernel.  Please make sure you have installed the kernel source files for your kernel and that they are properly configured; on Red Hat Linux systems, for example, be sure you have the 'kernel-source' or 'kernel-devel' RPM installed.  If you know the correct kernel source files are installed, you may specify the kernel source path with the '--kernel-source-path' command line option.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the error message:

> Please make sure you have installed the kernel source files for your kernel

And that's simple enough. You actually don't need the full source, just the headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

On a side-note, be careful what guides you follow. If it's about graphics and it's older than 12 months, it's probably starting to fall behind the current state of things.

Comment: I installed that but I still get that error

Comment: @user1936987 I've changed the package slightly.

Comment: that's installed correctly thanks to you but know I don't have anythings on my desktop , no launcher , no top menu and for example the win key dosen't work. why ? is this normal?

Comment: And another problem is I can't switch between two software for example between chromium and vlc.Is this my fault or something else?